# UIButton grid activate same time dragging

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a grid of various UIButtons (5 x 5)... Now I have a UIControlEventTouchUpInside.. this means that when the user wants to choose various buttons need to press each, one by one...

How can I do to activate the buttons when the user is dragging his finger over various buttons.

Here is the code I use:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_caselles; i++) 
{
   lletra = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(POS_H, POS_V, mida_boto, mida_boto)];
   [botones addObject: lletra];
   [lletra setTitle: [caselles objectAtIndex: i] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
   lletra.tag = i; 
   [lletra addTarget:self action:@selector(lletraPitjada:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I resolved this way :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];


    for(UIButton*boton in botones) 
    {
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([boton frame], location) && boton.tag != boton_anterior) 
    { 
       boton_anterior = boton.tag;
       [self lletraPitjada:boton];
    }
    }

}
```

I override/commented the button set action, because is not working for me :

```
//[lletra addTarget:self action:@selector(lletraPitjada:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

and deactive user interaction, because UITouch dont like buttons :

```
lletra.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

And voilà... all is working perfect...

Answer (score 0):

You can also react to:

UIControlEventTouchDragEnter or
UIControlEventTouchDragExit

to handle these cases.

Comment: Yes I have also tried this events, but are not working, only the first button responds to drag, the others I are not affected while I'm draggin over...